# Initializing a map in a non-pointer type function in Go

Tags: dictionary, go, pointers, struct

I'm sure there's a good explanation for this, but I've not been able to find it. Can anyone help me understand what is happening the following code example?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type work struct {
    data map[string]string
}

func (w work) doSome() {
    w.data = make(map[string]string)
    w.data["k1"] = "v1"
}

func main() {
    work := work{}
    work.doSome()
    if work.data == nil {
        fmt.Println("data is nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("data is", work.data)
    }
}
```

This prints out `data is nil`, which is not what I expected. If I rework this to be a pointer type (i.e. `*work`) for `doSome` method , it initializes the struct's variable. I'd like to understand why these are different. I assume it's something to do with `map` being a pointer, of sorts, but haven't been able to find a good reference to explain this.

Playground link - https://play.golang.org/p/lTN11TRkRNj

Comment: I think I found the answer I was looking for here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-type. "If the method needs to mutate the receiver, the receiver must be a pointer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a value receiver (`func (w work) doSome()`) the function gets a copy of the `work` struct. When it sets `w.data`, it is set for that copy, not for the instance of `work` declared in `main`.

Maps are essentially reference types, so if you initialized the map in main, this would've worked:

```
func (w work) doSome() {
    w.data["k1"] = "v1"
}

func main() {
    work := work{data:map[string]string{}}
    work.doSome()
}
```

Or, you should use a pointer receiver, so the `work` declared in `main` is sent to `doSome` as a pointer:

```
func (w *work) doSome() {
    w.data = make(map[string]string)
    w.data["k1"] = "v1"
}

func main() {
    work := work{}
    work.doSome()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The comment about the function getting a copy of the struct is the bit I was looking for!